# VBA Macro to extract strings from word doc

Tags: vba, excel

i have a word document containing several strings. These strings have the first part always the same, for example ABC_001, ABC_002, ABC_003. I need to search for "ABC_" substring in the doc, extract all the occurences ("ABC_001", "ABC_002", "ABC_003") and copy them in an Excel sheet. 
Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in VBA and i haven't tried any solution yet, cause i didn't find a way to search a string starting from a substring, but always the opposite, find a substring from string, that it isn't what i need. I should solve this searching problem before try any attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 and regex them.
Have a look at http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba/

and http://txt2re.com/

and some of [VBA multiple matches within one string using regular expressions execute method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084909/vba-multiple-matches-within-one-string-using-regular-expressions-execute-method)

EDIT:
Actually it is probably easier to go to data and "Get external data" choose de-limiter and import, either manually or record a macro to get a feeling for the vba structure.

This should get you all the entrys in seperate cells, then go over them with a [MID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the part you need

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but if i correctly understood, MID searches for a number of characters inside a string. I'm looking for a function, if exists, that starts from a substring to extract the entire string. Search for "ABC_" to extract "ABC_001".